# How to trigger callback function in javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I create popup confirmation with button like this

```
class Fn{
    confirm(params = {}){
       $('body').append(`<button onclick="params.confirm(this)">OK</button>`)
    }
}
```

on another page I call confirm function like this,

```
let fn = new Fn()

fn.confirm({
  message: 'Are you sure want to delete this?',
  textConfirm: 'Yes,
  confirm: (e) => {
    // run another function
    alert('Yeay!')
  }
})
```

I want when the button is clicked, then run another function,
how to do that? thanks for your help.

Comment: What prevents you from replacing `alert('Yeay!')` with your other function? Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: when I call fn.confirm() , alert('yeay'!) is appears before the button is clicked.

Comment: What do you expect `e` to be when that `params.confirm` is called?

Comment: you run another function where you have the comment `// run another function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
`<button onclick="params.confirm(this)">OK</button>`
```

In this `onclick` attribute, `params` refers to a global variable, not to the parameter of the `Fn.prototype.confirm` method.

To solve this, create your button the jQuery way, and bind the click handler with jQuery:

```js
class Fn {
    confirm(params = {}) {
        $("<button>").text("OK").appendTo('body').click(params.confirm.bind(params));
    }
}

let fn = new Fn()

fn.confirm({
    message: 'Are you sure want to delete this?',
    textConfirm: 'Yes',
    confirm: (e) => {
        alert('Yeay!');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```